# How to add prefix in glob.glob for path patching

Tags: python-2.7, glob

there:

I am trying to use a prefix as a input in glob.glob() function to pull out the png files in my folder. For example: I have dog_1.png, dog_2.png, bird_1.png, bird_2.png in this folder. my input is dog but for some reason, python pulled out nothing. Can you please do me a favor check where I did wrong? Thank you in advance!

```
dir_name = 'mypath'

if __name__=='__main__':
    prefix = raw_input('Input the prefix of images:')
    files = glob.glob( dir_name + prefix + '*.png')

    print files
```

What I got is []

Comment: Shouldn't that be `dir_name + '/' + prefix + '*.png'`?

Comment: ^ Yeah, it should.

Comment: Thank you! It works now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your path to `glob` is malformed. You'll need to specify your path like this: `dir_name/<file>.png` (note the forward slash `/`). You can do this nicely using `os.path.join`.

```
import os
glob.glob(os.path.join(dir_name, prefix + '*.png'))
```